# Chainlink Functions fulfillRequest failing due to callback gas limitation

Tags: chainlink

I'm facing a problem with the fulfillRequest from Chainlink Functions beta.
My callback function (fulfillRequest) is consistently failing and I don't get the successfull OCRResponse event.

I was initially unsure about what was going on but I could confirm that the problem was related to gasLimit when I inspected the transaction using Tenderly transaction debugger.
In the tenderly panel, the transaction seems to be requiring ~460_000 gas. And the Chainlink Functions callback gas limit is strictly limited to 300_000 as stated [here](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/resources/service-limits).

My callback is expensive because I'm using an insurance framework called GIF (Generic Insurance Framework) from [Etherisc](https://github.com/etherisc/gif-contracts) and it triggers a whole lot of other callbacks when the fulfillRequest arrives.

This is the (partially) failed fulfillRequest transaction: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x3f92816559ab76cf1969ee394a727e0ecb6159dca0ac4c98944ca91b2c48db74

This is the consumer/client contract: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xB59EF5D36eC439fF9e98746Fe7944275e81B0e45#readContract

Any chance this service limit can be removed, or raised, for my wallet for the sake of testing?

I'm confident that my custom function works fine since I tested it extensively using the [starter kit](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit) provided by Chainlink.

Finally, before giving Chainlink Functions a try I was using ChainLink AnyAPI and everything was working just fine, thus I believe there is no issue on my contracts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to increase it past the 300_000 max. It's in the engineering backlog to create a method for increasing it more.

Comment: Hi Richard, I have overcame that limitation by kind of spliting the expensive transaction in two. The fulfillRequest is much simpler now: it just saves the data returned by the function in the storage. Then I've implemented a Keeper to periodically check if there is any new data, and if so, it executes the rest of the expensive callbacks. You can see it in action here: https://github.com/Rainsurance/rainsurance-contracts/blob/clfunctions/contracts/rain/RainOracleCLFunctions.sol